# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Series'

Tags: python, pandas

New to python. Using VS Code to run the code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_data = [10, 20, 30]

s = pd.Series(data=my_data)

print(s)
```

Trying to run this simple code but when I am using VS Code to run it I am getting the following error.
**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Series'**

Note: my filename is **pandas.py**

But when I am trying to run the same code using Jupyter Notebook, it is running perfectly. In case of Jupyter my filename is **pandas.ipynb**

So, my question is do I always have to run the **pandas.Series** code using **.ipynb** extension?

Comment: *Note: my filename is pandas.py* That's your problem.  Importing will prefer a local path over user-wide and system-wide paths.  It's seeing your pandas.py file and stopping there.  Your .ipynb file will never conflict -- it'll never find it as the python interpreter doesn't care about .ipynb files.

Comment: You really shouldn't name your file the same as the module. it should be somethind like pandas_learning.py. You may be replacing the pandas module entirely by naming it so. Have you tried naming it something different?(which to be specific changing it from .py to .jpynb is a type of renaming)

Comment: Apart from @jetwards said, don't forget to delete the pandas.pyc generated on import pandas or else it will keep failing.

Comment: Thanks guys. Followed your suggestion and fixed the problem.